# Trying to use Azure Storage Emulator in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to implement the Azure Storage Emulator in Laravel 5.8

It works on Azure dev & production, but not on Windows locally. Postman returns

```
"message": "Fail:\nCode: 403\nValue: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\ndetails (if any): .",
    "exception": "MicrosoftAzure\\Storage\\Common\\Exceptions\\ServiceException",
    "file": "C:\\Code\\web-portal-laravel\\vendor\\microsoft\\azure-storage-common\\src\\Common\\Internal\\ServiceRestProxy.php",
```

Like the public and private folders, we're trying to implement this as a Storage disk. We thought that just using the same sort of entries - but instead using the shared Key credentials in the .env file would work:

```
    AZURE_STORAGE_URL_EMU = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/local"
    AZURE_STORAGE_KEY_EMU = 
        "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
    AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_EMU = "devstoreaccount1"
    AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_EMU = "local"
```

The Storage Explorer is installed and sees the Blob, Queues and Table. And the status of the Emulator reports:

```
    Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
    IsRunning: True
    BlobEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10000/
    QueueEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10001/
    TableEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10002/
```

I have no idea what kind of Authorization header would allow this to work.

We're using the matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the section [`Connect to the emulator account using the well-known account name and key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#connect-to-the-emulator-account-using-the-well-known-account-name-and-key) of the offical document `Use the Azure storage emulator for development and testing`, the connnection string of Azure Storage Emulator should be as below.

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;
TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;
QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;
```

After I reviewed the source code [`src/AzureStorageServiceProvider.php`](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage/blob/master/src/AzureStorageServiceProvider.php) of [`matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage`](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage) plugin, I found the code as the figure below only supports the connection string of Azure Storage on cloud, not for Emulator.

[image]

So if without changing any code of the plugin, the workaround to configure the `config/filesystems.php` file as the content of `README` of the plugin repo said is as below.

```
'azure' => [
        'driver'    => 'azure',
        'name'      => 'devstoreaccount1',
        'key'       => 'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;',
        'container' => env('AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER'),
        'url'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_URL'),
        'prefix'    => null,
],
```

Then, the emulator connection string could be correctly complemented by the `key` value above with the string template code `'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s'`.

Comment: Brilliant! That was exactly it - the key needed to have all the info in it. Cheers!

Comment: I'm getting the error  MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException : Fail:
Code: 407
Value: Proxy Authorization Required